# Texturing an asteroid

Tags: textures, uv-mapping

I'm trying to texture this asteroid so it looks reasonable.  I'm missing something though.

Following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTUPU8QI6oM), I got this so far.

[image]

Now I don't understand the next step: **how do you resolve the seam problems**?  This icosahedral sphere has a seam running through it that cannot be avoided.  Ok.  How do I paint the texture so it **looks seamless** when applied to the object?  How do I know which edge connects to what side?  I guess it will just be symmetrical?

[image]

This seems awfully hard to texture a simple sphere.  Am I missing some technique here?

Answer (score 10):

This is where I will use a 3D painting program. I primarily use Blender for my modeling, and it has a 3D painter built in. Being able to paint directly on the model in a 3D environment, makes the strokes continue across seams.

I don't find the paint tools in Blender to be great, so I'll usually switch to something like [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) once I've got a rough idea. Then I add details in GIMP. Though, your 3D paint program may be different.

The program you use will depend on your work flow, but here's [a tutorial](http://www.blendtuts.com/texture_painting) (and [another](http://www.masterprim.com/blender-texturing/3d-texture-paint-with-sculpty/texture-paint-mode.php)) for using Blender's 3D painting capability.

[image]

Comment: Blender has the external edit feature where you can use perspective painting using different applications (such as GIMP) (it basically creates a screenshot on which you can paint and then apply)

Comment: Also note that many of these applications allow you to use a texture as a brush. So your rock noise texture could easily be applied in a seamless fashion.

Comment: Well it turns out there's a world of 3D texture tools for this purpose.. [Mudbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudbox), [ZBrush](http://www.pixologic.com/), and [Deep Paint 3D](http://www.righthemisphere.com/products/dp3d/Deep3D_UV/index.html) all support "3d texturing".  I knew these programs existed, I just haven't had a need for them.  Maya also has it's own 3D texture paint program.

Comment: Maybe I should use [Ptex](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxNlAlOuQQQ)

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to keep the background of the asteroid very flat so it wraps well, then add detail away from the edges. Don't cross the edge. Put your craters and bumps and things inside. That should minimize the seam.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get a reasonable wrap using this kind of UV layout:

[image]

It's only got 2 seams, one in the top, and one in the bottom (edges 1 and 7 from the diagram above).

The texture is tileable, so along the rest of the seam, it is seamless.

I couldn't figure out another way to do it!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also thought just now about using a *cubemap* texture (ie 6 textures).  My rationale is, if you were planning to use a 256x256=65536 texel image, you may as well use a 64x64x6=24576 texel image (cheaper!) and get less distortion and no poles.

You lay the UV mapping out like this:

[image: uv map]

Identifying what side is what and laying out the UV's this way is tedious but not very hard.

You have to create a *cubemap* texture to put on the sphere.  I didn't have a rocky one, so I just used one from http://humus.name/.  It's important to note tileability *isn't* enough for a cubemap:  you have to have continuity across the *edges* of the cubemap (just fold a paper cube to figure these out!)

Comment: A [.mb with this solution is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hoqukxiq932imql/cubemappedSphere.zip)

Comment: I just realized if your object is roughly spherical, you would not _need_ a UV layout.. you could just use the vertex normal for texcoord lookup into a cubemap.

Answer (score 1):

You could texture map it by pretending it's a sphere or a cube. The quality of this approximation depends on how round your asteroids are.

With sphere treat each vertex position as a normal and convert them to polar coordinates. This will create poles though, but at least it will be seamless.

With cube you can create 6 faces that are seamless. Alternatively you can just use a cube map by again treating all vertex positions as normals and sampling from a cube map with that.